# How to fetch single row in model and use in view in laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel

> I am new to Laravel so i don't know how to retrieve single row in
>   model and send it to the view without defining the route. below is thw
>   model code.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class mapLayers extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'XYZ';

    protected $fillable = array('abc','stagingabc','XYZlayer','XYZtoken');

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

> and what to use it to view e.g

```
 @$selectlayer= App\mapLayers->get();
    <script>

     var xyz="{{ $selectlayer->abc }}";
         var stagingabc ="{{ $selectlayer->stagingabc }}";

         </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`get()` for fetch all rows **ref link** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models

`first()` to fetch single row **ref link** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

```php
$selectlayer= \App\mapLayers::first();
    <script>
        var xyz="{{ $selectlayer->abc }}";
        var stagingabc ="{{ $selectlayer->stagingabc }}";
    </script>
```

Comment: give me an error Undefined variable: selectlayer (View: project\resources\views\abc.blade.php)

Comment: @sumitkundan i updated now check and you can use App\mapLayers::find($id);  find method as well to search by id

Comment: i don't have any id, same error thrown undefine variable selectlayer

Comment: then u should debug your application

Comment: How can i am totally new to Laravel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205499/discussion-between-sumit-kundan-and-kamlesh-paul).